# PrintToPdf Specific Frame

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, electron, quasar-framework

I'm using Electron's `printToPDF` to print the rendered html to a pdf.

My problem now is since my desktop app has several frames (side panel aka drawer that is always open), the side panel is also included in the PDF.

How can I use `printToPDF` so that only the middle panel (or let's say 1 specific vue component/instance) will be exported to the pdf?

Here is my current code:

```
    this.$q.electron.remote.getCurrentWebContents().webContents.printToPDF({ printBackground: true }).then(data => {
      fs.writeFile(pdfPath, data, err => {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log('Write PDF successfully.')
      })
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
```

Thanks!